# Is it possible to construct a Python date using only standard libs with a http string timestamp

Tags: python

I have string timestamps like this:

"Wed, 31 Jul 2013 13:03:38 GMT"

I couldn't see anything in python docs but I might have missed it.

Or if not, I assume I could do some parsing of the string - because it has a set format.  any pointers on how to get started would be helpful.

The dates are RFC 822 compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You need to use `strptime()`

```
import time
time.strptime("30 Nov 00", "%d %b %y")
```

Here is the link to the documentation:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime

Comment: I did this in the end: testdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')  where s is string.